# Android Buttons aren't visible

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem: the buttons from b0 to b9 and the button "Raspuns_user" are not visible on the screen.
How should I use Relative and Linear Layout in this case?

The buttons from b0 to b9 are keyboard numbers and I've put them in a LinearLayout beacuse I want them to stay in rows.

Any suggestions?

thank you!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/banda"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:id="@+id/banda_bk"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/obj1"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginRight="67dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/printfirst"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/answer" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/ImageView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
        android:src="@drawable/obj2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="121dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>   <!-- la inceput toate invisible-->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/ImageView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
        android:src="@drawable/obj3"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="121dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>    <!-- la inceput toate invisible-->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/ImageView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
        android:src="@drawable/obj4"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="121dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>   <!-- la inceput toate invisible-->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/ImageView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
        android:src="@drawable/obj5"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="121dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/Scor"
        android:id="@+id/textViewScor"
        android:layout_marginRight="34dp"
        android:textColor="@color/textbody"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:text="0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/printfirst"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewScor"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/printfirst"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/printsecond"
        android:layout_below="@+id/printfirst"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/printfirst"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/printfirst"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Raspunsul tau"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/printsecond"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/printsecond" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/correctanswer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/printsecond"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/printsecond"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/printsecond"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Verifica si genereaza alte nr"
        android:id="@+id/buton2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/correctanswer"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/printsecond"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/printsecond" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Raspuns_user"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="40sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:text="@string/b0"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:text="@string/b1"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:text="@string/b2"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:text="@string/b3"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:text="@string/b4"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:text="@string/b5"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:enabled="false" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:text="@string/b6"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:text="@string/b7"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:text="@string/b8"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:text="@string/b9"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: android:layout_height="0dp" change to "wrap-content"

Comment: But I don't understand something: If I change the "big layout" from Relative to Linear, why they still don't appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `layout_height="0dp` to `wrap_content` and also set the

`android:layout_width="0dp"` from the buttons to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: For fruther interaction in stackoverflow, you can accept answers

Answer (score 0):

Change the height of Linear layout from

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**

Problem with Your layout is that you have used `android:layout_height="0dp"`

instead of that use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

**More Info :**

**`LinearLayout` is used to set layout childs either HORIZONTAL or VERTICAL.**
So it set positions as you declared in XML but it doesn't happen with  `RelativeLayout`.
In **`RelativeLayout` you have to set positions of your `childViews`**.

Its the basic difference between both layouts..

You are using [`RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

It uses properties like below to set positions of `ChildViews` in layout screen

```
android:layout_above
android:layout_below
android:layout_toLeftOf
android:layout_toRightOf
```

read about [Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) for more details...

Hope this helps...